# Image won't move when I press corresponding keys in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I just started writing code for fun and to learn something new, however I've run into this issue and would like some specific input as to what I'm doing wrong. At this point in my project I'm trying to make an image move left and right with the arrow keys. I've gotten the image to display properly but it does not move in response to pressing the keys. Any input would be welcome.

```
`import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Invader slim")
surface = screen.get_rect()

DIS = (100, 100)
pygame.image.load('sprite_soldier.png')
player_image = pygame.image.load('sprite_soldier.png').convert_alpha()
player_soldier = pygame.transform.scale(player_image, DIS)
player = screen.blit(player_soldier, (screen_width/2 - 10, screen_height - 100))

bg_color = pygame.Color(0, 100, 100)
green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
white = pygame.Color('white')
light_gray = pygame.Color(200, 200, 200)


torpedo = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 10, screen_height - 100, 20, 20)

player_x = player.x
move_left = False
move_right = False


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = False
    if move_right:
        player_x += 10
    elif move_left:
        player_x -= 10

    if player.x >= screen_width:
        move_right = False
    if player.x <= 0:
        move_left = False

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to draw the player at its new position in the application loop:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    screen.fill(0)
    player = screen.blit(player_soldier, (player_x, screen_height - 100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) instead of the `KEYDOWN` event:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player_x += 10 * (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT])

    screen.fill(0)
    player = screen.blit(player_soldier, (player_x, screen_height - 100))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a sequence with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Invader slim")
surface = screen.get_rect()

DIS = (100, 100)
player_image = pygame.image.load('sprite_soldier.png').convert_alpha()
player_soldier = pygame.transform.scale(player_image, DIS)
player_rect = player_soldier.get_rect(midbottom =  (screen_width/2, screen_height))

bg_color = pygame.Color(0, 100, 100)
green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
white = pygame.Color('white')
light_gray = pygame.Color(200, 200, 200)


torpedo = pygame.Rect(screen_width/2 - 10, screen_height - 100, 20, 20)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player_rect.x += 10 * (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT])
    player_rect.clamp_ip(surface)

    screen.fill(0)
    player = screen.blit(player_soldier, player_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the image to the screen again each frame. You can do something like this:

```
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width, screen_height = 1280, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Invader slim")

DIS = (100, 100)
player_image = pygame.image.load('sprite_soldier.png').convert_alpha()
player_soldier = pygame.transform.scale(player_image, DIS)
player_rect = player_soldier.get_rect(center=screen_width / 2 - 10, screen_height - 100)

bg_color = pygame.Color(0, 100, 100)
green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
white = pygame.Color('white')
light_gray = pygame.Color(200, 200, 200)
   
torpedo = pygame.Rect(screen_width / 2 - 10, screen_height - 100, 20, 20)

move_left = False
move_right = False


def draw():
   screen.fill(bg_color)
   screen.blit(player_soldier, player_rect)
   pygame.display.update()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left = False

    if move_right:
        player_rect.x += 10
    elif move_left:
        player_rect.x -= 10

    if player_rect.x >= screen_width:
        move_right = False
    if player_rect.x <= 0:
        move_left = False

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

I also changed some stuff like adding a player_rect variable.
And I also tried to make it a little bit more readable with the FPS variable and some blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

You've updated the position of the player but have not blitted the sprite to that new position. Also you have to "Clear" the screen before you blit you updates otherwise you are just going to be painting a line.

```
# screen.fill() will 'clear' the screen of previous blits
screen.fill('black)

# Show the player at the new position
screen.blit(player_soldier, (player_x, screen_height - 100))

# pygame.display.flip() will show the updated screen
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

The screen must be cleared before drawing/bliting sprites. This prevents the smear effect.

Sprites have to be redrawn/blited to the screen every frame to achieve 'movement'.

These two steps must be done every frame before the new screen is displayed.